# How to pass a bool to a JavaScript function from code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms, boolean

I have a JavaScript function as follows:

```javascript
function A(bNeed)
{
    if (bNeed){
        ...
    }
    else{
        ...
    }
}
```

In my code behind, in `Page_Load`, I have

```csharp
bool bNeed = File.Exists(...);
btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("return A('{0}');", bNeed));
```

But it doesn't seem to work correctly. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are passing capitalized `'True'` and `'False'` as quoted strings, but the JavaScript Boolean literals are lowercase `true` and `false` without quotes. Change it to:

```
btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("return A({0});", bNeed ? "true" : "false");
```

(If you prefer, you could write `bNeed.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()` instead of `bNeed ? "true" : "false"` because `Boolean.ToString()` returns `"True"` and `"False"`.)

Comment: Instead of `bNeed ? "true" : "false"` I'd recommend `bNeed.ToString().ToLower()`

Comment: @LeastOne -- Typo there:  `ToLower()`.  Was going to recommend the same thing.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher You've never used the `.ToLoser()` method eh? I suppose `.ToLower()` is more appropriate :)

Comment: @LeastOne @Jeremy: `ToLower()` is (theoretically) culture-sensitive. `ToLowerInvariant()` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @LeastOne In french it's called "lapsus" :D